# Wrapping tables with minipages?

Tags: tables, minipage

Say I have the following table:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}     
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a test table}
    \label{tab:test}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
    \toprule
    Letter & Stuff \\ \midrule
    A & 1 \\
    B & 2 \\
    C & 3 \\
    D & 4 \\
    E & 5 \\
    F & 6 \\
    G & 7 \\
    H & 8 \\
    I & test \\
    J & test2\\
    K & test3 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I would like this table to split itself in half and to be next to each other, maybe using minipages. A photoshop for better explanation:
[image: Photoshop]

The reason I want to do this instead of just making 4 columns is, that this is supposed to be an alphabetically sorted table that I will add stuff to over time. I can't do this with more columns.

Comment: With other words: Finally there might be two tables aside with at most 13 rows? (Assuming standard 26 letters alphabet?)

Comment: @PhilNope you can put two `tabular` environments into `table` environment. Then, control the space between tabulars with `\hspace` command

Comment: The amount of rows is not limited. I want the table to dynamically "wrap" to the right. Similar to Word if you create a environment of two columns in a page.

Comment: @juanuni: I think the real question here is the automatically splitting at half of the rows

Comment: Maybe one can limit the vertical space available to a table and it automatically wraps when this space is reached? It doesn't necessarily have to be at half - it just has to support me adding items after it's finished.

Comment: @PhilNope: You are asking for `reflow` of tables... I think this is difficult, but perhaps there's a package already for this

Comment: You can use the `supertabular` environment in two columns. The documentation is here http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/supertabular/supertabular.pdf.

Comment: @AboAmmar: Will you provide an answer? Apparently you have experience with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\begin{center}
\tablehead{%
\toprule\multicolumn{1}{l}{Letter} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Stuff} \tabularnewline \midrule}
\tablelasttail{\bottomrule}
%
\begin{supertabular}{p{1cm}p{2cm}}
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
A & Test text \tabularnewline
B & Test text \tabularnewline
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\onecolumn
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for, thank you for the example.